# How to remove port number from URL when running npm start?

Tags: url, port, json-server

I'm working on a create-react-app and I want to remove the port number from the URL that gets created when I run npm start in my api. Right now, my start  scripts contains this:

```
"start": "json-server --host https://my-json-server.typicode.com/vbrambila2/1RM"
```

This is the URL I want my api tp run on. But when I run npm start, it gets initiated as:

```
https://my-json-server.typicode.com/vbrambila2/1RM:3000
```

I also get this error in my terminal:

```
  Resources
  http://https://my-json-server.typicode.com/vbrambila2/1RM:3000/movements

  Home
  http://https://my-json-server.typicode.com/vbrambila2/1RM:3000

Some error occurred Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://my-json-server.typicode.com/vbrambila2/1RM
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:69:26) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'https://my-json-server.typicode.com/vbrambila2/1RM'
```

Does anyone know how I can get it to start as just the URL I provided and not add the :3000?

Answer (score 1):

Any HTTP URL without the port specified implicitly specifies port 80 (HTTP) or port 443 (HTTPS). Eg.

`http://example.com` => `http://example.com:80`

`https://example.com` => `https://example.com:443`

To avoid typing in the port number, you should serve your content on port 443 (since you are using HTTPS). You haven't told us what framework you are using to host your server, but typically the CLI options for setting ports is either '-p' or '--port', although you should read the documentation page for your framework first.

Edit:

Based on your tags, I'm inferring that you're using `json-server` in which case, adding `-p 443` to your start command should set the port appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I added -p 443 to my start command and got the same response, but with 443 instead of 3000 this time. I updated my question to include the error I get in the terminal when I run npm start.

Comment: It appears that json-server is trying to serve over http, instead of https. I believe the solution is to drop the `https://` at the start of your host option, and change the port to 80. However, if you need to serve over HTTPS, I would recommend reading the json-server documentation at 'https://github.com/typicode/json-server#https' which gives some pointers for setting up SSL.

Answer (score 1):

On your .env file you must add `HTTPS=true` and `PORT=443`